# Out of the primeval spirit of place Sertor made it, 2237

Tags: translation-check

For an inscription:

Out of the primeval spirit of place Sertor made it, 2237
EX·GENIUS·LOCI·PRIMAEVVS·SERTOR·FECIT·MMCCXXXVII

Is it correct? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not grammatical.  The following is the equivalent grammatical version of your text:

> EX·GENIO·LOCI·PRIMAEVO·SERTOR·FECIT·MMCCXXXVII

I think this is a reasonable version of what I think you want, but I will leave it to others to suggest other possible wordings.